# Double-throw switch with no common connection?

Tags: switches, dpdt

I need a DT, ON-OFF-ON switch to control two independent circuits with no common connection. I need something that behaves like either A and B, or C and D in the diagram below. Does such a thing exist?  This seems pretty straightforward, but I haven't been able to find one.

In the diagram, A closes one circuit and B closes the other; the other possible configuration would be one in which C closes one and D closes the other.

[image: Diagram showing required switch configuration]

**update:**

Thanks for the suggestions.  Here's how the switch I bought works and how the pins are configured.  I just need to put a jumper across 2 and 5, which are common, and connect one circuit to 1 and 4 and the other circuit to 3 and 6.

[image: DPDT switch diagram]

Comment: If you want to control *2 independent circuits*, then you may want to look into *Double Pole* switches.  *Double Pole* is not the same thing as *Double Throw*, even though it's sometimes implemented in a single DPDT switch.

Comment: A DPDT switch would satisfy your A-B situation as long as you can accept 1-3 & 2-4 in A and 4-6 & 3-5 in B.

Comment: I think if I had drawn a normal DPDT switch, 3 and 4 would be common, the "up" position would connect 1 to 3 and 2 to 4, and the down position would connect 3 to 5 and 4 to 6.  So, if I permanently connect 3 to 4, I could connect one circuit to connectors 1 and 2, and the other circuit to connectors 5 and 6. Does this seem right?

Comment: 3 and 4 are not common in a normal DPDT switch. A normal DPDT has 2 completely electrically independent switches with a common physical control level/knob/slider/whatever.

Comment: Terminals 1, 3, and 5 are one pole of the switch, and 2, 4, and 6 are the other.  Connect one circuit to terminals 1 and 3, and the other circuit to terminals 4 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ZG0i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Right.  So in this diagram I would permanently connect 1 and 6.  Circuit A (nothing to do with my diagram) would connect to 3 and 4, and circuit B would connect to 2 and 5.  Correct?

Comment: @DwaneReid: The terminal numbers in your drawing do not match the terminal numbers in the OP's drawings (at least, not for DPDT switches I've used).

Comment: @dcorsello:  You would connect one circuit to terminals 1 and 3, and the other to 6 and 5 (using Dwayne's numbering)

Comment: @PeterBennett: The terminals in the original question do NOT refer to an actual physical switch. What is clear is that one pole of the switch moves the armature (pin 1) between pins 2&3. The other armature (pin 6) moves between pins 4&5.

Answer (score 0):

An ON-OFF-ON switch is a three position switch, with the middle position disconnecting everything. If that's what you want, then you'll need a Double-Pole-Double-Throw switch with a center-off position. There's an excellent selection at **[DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/switches/toggle-switches/1114212?k=toggle%20switch&pv235=2&FV=fff40011%2Cfff80064%2C2080004&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)**

A Double-Pole switch comprises two independent switches in the same housing, and  most DPDT switches have the commons as the center terminals and the made contacts on the opposite side of the switch with reference to the tip of the toggle.

When you go to wire it, if it's a conventional switch, the wiring should go like this:

[image]

In any case, you should test continuity with the toggle in its various positions in order to decide which circuit goes where.

Answer (score 0):

You just described a common DPDT switch, just with center-off.

It's even simpler.  Here I've drawn in how to do it on your switch's diagram.

I also scrawled in an [old fashioned knife switch](https://people.duke.edu/~ng46/topics/switch-rotary-dpdt.jpg) with brass blades and a purple handle (for Prince) so you can visualize what's going on.  Purple is an insulator.

[image]

Comment: The only reason to do as you describe in your edit (connect "one circuit" to 3 and 6, and bridge 2-5) is if you need a double air-gap to snuff the arc of a particularly high voltage or high inductance.